# How do I trace a path in matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, matrix, path-finding

I have matrix like below:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

How can I find a path to trace 1's in the matrix? As you can see the matrix's 1s represent something like the word "U2", I want to return a path something like pixels it should follow to draw it. It can move back a path if it has already moved forward, but it should not jump a 0, it should always move on the 1s.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble understanding what you need. Don't the 1s represent such a path? If you want to draw it, you can convert the background to say black, and the 1s to something like white in RGB.

Comment: What you want to do is very similar to doing a graphical [seed or flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), so you may be able to adapt the algorithm for doing it to produce the results you desire.

Comment: The issue with your question is how to choose which path to go if more than 1 path is available. This makes it depend on some path-finding method. You can set all the 0s as walls and then use [Bellman Ford method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) for pathfinding using diffusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]


class U2:

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.solved = []

    def find_path(self):
        for line in self.matrix:
            comprehension = ["___" if item==1 else item=="x" for item in line]             
            self.solved.append(comprehension)
        return self.solved



a = U2(a)
solved = a.find_path()
for i in solved:
    print(i)
```

Something like this?
This is the output:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, '___', False, False, '___', '___', '___', '___', False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, '___', False, False, '___', False, False, '___', False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, '___', False, False, '___', False, False, '___', False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, '___', False, False, '___', False, False, '___', False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, '___', False, False, '___', '___', '___', '___', False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, '___', False, False, '___', False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, '___', False, False, '___', False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, '___', '___', '___', '___', '___', '___', '___', False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of lists with the positions of the number 1's that you can iterate through, you can do something like this:

```
>>>block = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

>>> answer = []
>>> for i in block:
...    answer.append([j for j, e in enumerate(i) if e == 1])

>>>answer
[[], [6, 9, 10, 11, 12], [6, 9, 12], [6, 9, 12], [6, 9, 12], [6, 9, 10, 11, 12], [6, 9], [6, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], []]
```